# Square Connect API V2: Setting item tax rates?

Tags: square-connect

Does an upsert on an item object set the tax rates on the item? The documentation is confusing and it sounds like it would only add new tax rates and not remove missing ones, but in testing it seems that it does both add and remove. Here is the relevant bit from the docs (https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-catalogitem):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the UpsertCatalogObject can add and remove tax_ids from a catalog object (whatever you upsert will be saved to the object). The UpdateItemTaxes is used if you don't want to change anything else in the item, so you don't need access to the whole item. With it, you don't need to send the whole object back, just the id and the tax_ids that you wish to enable and disable.